# How to add a Processing Instruction [jdom2]

Tags: java, jdom-2

When having a Processing Instruction

```
<?xml-stylesheet  type="application/xml"  href="catalog.xsl" ?>
```

How can it be added by [jdom2](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/docs.html) to an existing XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<catalog xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <foo:cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <bar:year>1985</bar:year>
    </foo:cd>
    <foo:cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <bar:year>1988</bar:year>
    </foo:cd>
    <foo:cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <bar:year>1982</bar:year>
    </foo:cd>
</catalog>
```

Just to complete the example, here is the XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/foo:cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="company"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="bar:year"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XSL doesn't matter here. Which Java code do you have to process the XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
ProcessingInstruction xsl = new ProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet","type='text/xsl' href='catalog.xsl'");
doc.addContent(0, xsl);
```

should work. Please add your code to get an answer that matches better your project.

Comment: Nice, also note that, if you want, you can use [the "pseudo attribute" methods](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/ProcessingInstruction.html#setPseudoAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to get/set the type and href individually if you want.